# Permission to allow JavaFX 8 windows to display always on top?

Tags: java, javafx, java-security-manager

I have the Java Security Manager enabled on my application along with a custom security policy configured in the project directory. I am trying to display a JavaFX window always on top, however with the Security Manager enabled, I am unable to do this.

After reviewing the Javadoc for `Stage#setAlwaysOnTop(boolean)`, I was left with this:

> There are differences in behavior between applications if a Security Manager is present. Applications with permissions are allowed to set "always on top" flag on a Stage. In applications without the proper permissions, an attempt to set the flag will be ignored and the property value will be restored to "false".
>
> The property is read only because it can be changed externally by the underlying platform and therefore must not be bindable.

I have tried searching online through other sources and the [official Oracle JavaFX 8 Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm) to at least hint me on what permission I should grant in my policy to allow JavaFX windows to display always on top, however I am out of luck.

Note: I do not want to grant my application `java.security.AllPermission`, I only want to grant my application the permissions that it requires.

Comment: If you were using JavaFX 9+ then you'd use [`javafx.util.FXPermission`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/util/FXPermission.html).

Comment: That's unfortunate since I'm forced to use Java 8 for my application.

Comment: Looking at at `openjfx/8u20/rt`, it looks like [they use `AllPermission`](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u20/rt/file/292cf1a8bc82/modules/graphics/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/tk/quantum/WindowStage.java#l556) for this, unfortunately. There's a comment mentioning possibly-needed finer-grained control, which I suppose comes in the form of `FXPermission` in FX 9.